# How to utilize and manipulate land coverage map in `RasterBrick` for area-weighted statistics in R?

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, data-manipulation

I have had land coverage map in `TIF` format that presumably used to calculate an area-weighted yearly mean temperature for Germany. I downloaded this land coverage map data from here ([direct download link of land coverage map for Europe](https://cidportal.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ftp/jrc-opendata/LUISA/PrimaryOutput/Europe/REF-2014/JRC_LUISA_Input_Corine_land_cover_2006_r_ref_2014.zip)). In particular, I intend to extract data of land/soil coverage for the city, agricultural area and vice-versa. In my first step, I imported this land coverage data with `raster` package. Here is my R script down below:

```
library(raster)
library(R.utils)
library(maptools)

url = "https://cidportal.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ftp/jrc-opendata/LUISA/PrimaryOutput/Europe/REF-2014/JRC_LUISA_Input_Corine_land_cover_2006_r_ref_2014.zip"
download.file(url, basename(url))
gunzip(basename(url))
rname <- list.files(getwd(), "tif$")

land_cover = raster::brick("~/LUISA_CLC_land_coverage/clc06_r.tif")
```

so far I am able to import original land coverage map in `RasterBrick` object in R. Note that original map was covered the whole europe, so I 
have to crop the regions that I am only interested in. To do so, I used `maptools` and `raster` package for clipping the map. Here is the R script down below:

```
data(wrld_simpl)
germany <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl@data$NAME == "Germany",]
germany <- spTransform(germany, CRSobj = land_cover@crs)
germany_land <- crop(land_cover, germany)
```

However, I assume that this cropped land coverage map in `RasterBrick` object better to be in grid `shapefile` with very high degree resolution, but how is it doable? Any idea?

The main point of raising this question is I need to retrieve all data of land/soil coverage for the city, agricultural area, and match this information to respective Germany NUTS-s level shapefile ([download link of Germany level 3 shapefile](https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsf/gadm36_DEU_3_sf.rds)).

I really don't have a solid idea how to utilize the data in this land coverage map for the sake of calculating area-weighted yearly mean temperature. Perhaps, a possible approach could be to retrieve land/soil coverage for the city, agricultural area data, then find match from Germany NUTS-3 level shapefile.

Here is how to get Germany' NUTS-3 shapefile( R script how to get Germany' NUTS-3 regions' shapefile in R):

```
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(R.utils)

url = "http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/GISCO/distribution/v2/nuts/download/ref-nuts-2013-03m.shp.zip"
download.file(url, basename(url))
gunzip(basename(url))

getwd()
setwd("~/ref-nuts-2013-03m.shp/")
list.files(pattern = 'NUTS_RG_03M_2013.*.shp$')

eu <- readOGR(dsn = getwd(), layer ="NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_2")
Germany_NUTS3 <- eu[eu@data$CNTR_CODE == "DE",]
```

So using this Gernamny' NUTS-3 shapefile, `Germany_NUTS3`, I want to extract all data of land/soil coverage for the city, agricultural area and vice-versa.

If such extraction of data from land coverage map in `RasterBrick`, how can I make this happen in R? Is that doable? Any efficient workaround to get this done? Any idea?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: what kind of information? The landcover data is just a raster with a class assigned to each pixel - so from the top of my head you could extract the pixels for each feature in your shapefile and calculate the percentage of each class

Comment: In the end it will depend on what your goal is ... I was just assuming since you have NUTS regions and a landcover raster, that would be a natural way to aggregate the information to each region. So let's say if one of these regions is covered by 1000 pixels, if 100 of them are labeled "bare soil" you could argue that 10% of that region is covered by bare soil (of course this conclusion will depend on the quality of your landcover data, and the more pixel the more robust the conclusion)

Comment: @Val my goal is, in each polygon, I want to see how many city or land coverage area can be found by using land coverage raster, if such match found, I want to see its area coverage information. Is that doable? Any possible things that can be done for this land coverage raster would be enough. I am quite curious about your thought? Any further elaboration? Thank you very much !

Comment: In the raster, each pixel has a distinct class ... so you could extract all the pixels for each polygon (have a look at the `raster` package's `extract` function). That could give you and idea about the distribution of landcover classes within each polygon. Further, you could get an estimate of area through methods like pixel counting, which directly relates to the raster's resolution ... but this is turning into a theoretical discussion, and SO isn't really the place for that. I suggest you read some literature and googling (e.g. land cover area estimate from land cover classification)

Comment: Like [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Michael_Wulder/publication/260138121_Good_Practices_for_Assessing_Accuracy_and_Estimating_Area_of_Land_Change/links/59e76ab3a6fdcc6433a947e1/Good-Practices-for-Assessing-Accuracy-and-Estimating-Area-of-Land-Change.pdf) or [this](https://www.unodc.org/documents/crop-monitoring/Workshop_coca_leaves/Javier_Gallego3.pdf) ... If you have a clear idea of what you want to do, you can think about the programmatical implementation. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Val  I think [JRC area estimation](https://www.unodc.org/documents/crop-monitoring/Workshop_coca_leaves/Javier_Gallego3.pdf) is quite close to my expectation. Could you elaborate your programmatic implementation in R? Thank you !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170717/discussion-between-val-and-andy-jian).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments and in chat, this would be a quick and dirty method (the JRC approach, amongst others, would be certainly a better way to do it but also much more effort)

So you have your landcover `land_cover` and your NUTS regions over Germany `Germany_NUTS3`:

```
# you can take the raster function since it's only one layer

land_cover <- raster::raster("~/LUISA_CLC_land_coverage/clc06_r.tif")

eu <- readOGR(dsn = getwd(), layer ="NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_2")
Germany_NUTS3 <- eu[eu@data$CNTR_CODE == "DE",]

# you can use Germany_NUTS straight for cropping the landcover, so we'll project it to the raster's coordinate system

Germany_NUTS3_projected <- spTransform(Germany_NUTS3, CRSobj = land_cover@crs)

land_cover_germany <- crop(land_cover, Germany_NUTS3_projected)
```

Now you can extract the landcover pixels for the NUTS region using `extract` from the raster package.

**BE AWARE: This can take some time, especially if the area or the raster is big or you have many polygons. If you need to do this repeatedly, you might want to use a different approach.**

As an example, I'll do it for one of the NUTS regions:

```
pixel_extract <- raster::extract(land_cover_germany,Germany_NUTS3_projected[2,])
```

If you use more polygons at once, `pixel_extract` will be a list of vectors with pixel values with each element representing a different polygon.

In this exemplary case, there's only one element, showing the landcover class values for the pixels within this polygon:

```
> head(pixel_extract)
[[1]]
   [1] 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
  [24] 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
  [47] 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
  [70] 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
  [93] 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 [116] 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 23 23 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 [139] 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24  4 ...
```

Now, to derive the area covered by your classes of interest, you need to count the pixels and then multiply them with the area of a single pixel.
Since the resolution of a single pixel is 100 by 100 meters, the area is 10000 m2.

To identify the land cover values of your desired classes, we can take a look into the `LUISA_legend.xls` file which comes with the raster:

> ```
>    GRID_CODE CLC_CODE LABEL
>     1   111 Artificial surfaces
>     2   112 Artificial surfaces
>     3   121 Artificial surfaces
>     4   122 Artificial surfaces
>     5   123 Artificial surfaces
>     6   124 Artificial surfaces
>     7   131 Artificial surfaces
>     8   132 Artificial surfaces
>     9   133 Artificial surfaces
>     10  141 Artificial surfaces
>     11  142 Artificial surfaces
>     12  211 Agricultural areas
>     13  212 Agricultural areas
>     14  213 Agricultural areas
>     15  221 Agricultural areas
>     16  222 Agricultural areas
>     17  223 Agricultural areas
>     18  231 Agricultural areas
>     19  241 Agricultural areas
>     20  242 Agricultural areas
>     21  243 Agricultural areas
>     22  244 Agricultural areas
> ```

So to count the pixels, we just see which values are between 1 and 11 for artificial surfaces, and between 12 and 22 for agriculture. To get an area "estimate" we can calculate the number of pixels with the area of a single pixel.

```
areas <-data.frame(ARTIFICIAL_AREA=sum(pixel_extract[[1]]>=1 &  pixel_extract[[1]]<=11) * (100*100),
           AGRICULTURE_AREA=sum(pixel_extract[[1]]>=12 &  pixel_extract[[1]]<=22) * (100*100))
```

This gives you an area estimate in square meters:

```
> areas
  ARTIFICIAL_AREA AGRICULTURE_AREA
1       954030000       9282970000
```

If `pixel_extract` is a list with an element per polygon (that is if you used the full shapefile), you can calculate the areas with `lappy` and use `do.call(rbind,` to create a single dataframe:

```
areas <- lapply(pixel_extract, function(x) data.frame(ARTIFICIAL_AREA=sum(x >=1 &  x <=11) * (100*100),
                   AGRICULTURE_AREA=sum(x>=12 & x<=22) * (100*100))

areas_df <- do.call(rbind,areas)
```